# extracting a number from a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, numbers

I have a string with a number inside and I want to retrieve that number.
for example if I have a string "bla bla 45 bla bla" I want to get the number 45.
I have searched a bit and found out that this code should make the work

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("bla bla 45 bla bla");
if(matcher.matches())
    String result = matcher.group();
```

but it doesn't :( 
probably the problem is that "\d+" regular expression is converted to "^\d+$" and so the matcher doesn't matches the number inside the text.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `matcher.find()` instead.

Answer (score 11):

Here's an example on how to use **matcher.find()**

```
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("bla bla 45 bla 22 bla");
    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

This will output

```
45
22
```