# Extract numbers from an alpha numeric string using android

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have to extract only numeric values from `String str="sdfvsdf68fsdfsf8999fsdf09"`.
How can I extract numbers from an alpha numeric string in android?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558432/extracting-a-number-from-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
String str="sdfvsdf68fsdfsf8999fsdf09";
String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

update:

```
String str="fgdfg12°59'50\" Nfr | gdfg: 80°15'25\" Efgd";
String[] spitStr= str.split("\\|");

String numberOne= spitStr[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
String numberSecond= spitStr[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Comment: If used this I am getting only alphabets, but I need only numeric values

Comment: @Prasanth_AndroidJD: You might consider selecting this answer as the correct solution by marking it to go along with your thanks. ;-)

Comment: string str="fgdfg12°59'50" Nfr | gdfg: 80°15'25" Efgd" , can u plz help me here to extract this value to number only

Comment: @Prasanth_AndroidJD Replace your string with this String str = "fgdfg12°59'50\" Nfr | gdfg: 80°15'25\" Efgd";.

Comment: yes u r right, but ma problem is i had ma values in ma table as String str= "fgdfg12°59'50" Nfr | gdfg: 80°15'25" Efgd", so here how can i add \ to each(double quotes ")  .. thank you in advance

Comment: get value from Table by cursor, assign to string= cursor.getString();
String numberOnly= string.str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

Comment: Here in this  String str= "fgdfg12°59'50" Nfr | gdfg: 80°15'25" Efgd",after (|) I have to separate the numeric values into 2 values like 125950   801525, Thanks in advance

Comment: How to extract for this :: <html>... <aherf ....idh=1002> HI..<ahref=....>HOW R U..</html>, Here I have extract Hi.. and How R U.. only as my Output, how can i extract for this scenario .. Help please regarding this issue.. Thanks in advance again..

Answer (score 4):

```
public static String getOnlyNumerics(String str) {

    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }

    StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() ; i++) {
        c = str.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            strBuff.append(c);
        }
    }
    return strBuff.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int extractNumberFromAnyAlphaNumeric(String alphaNumeric) {
    alphaNumeric = alphaNumeric.length() > 0 ? alphaNumeric.replaceAll("\\D+", "") : "";
    int num = alphaNumeric.length() > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(alphaNumeric) : 0; // or -1 
    return num;
}
```

You can set the value to 0 or -1 (what to do if no number is found in the alphanumeric at all) as per your needs