# Exctract values from given text in android

Tags: android, regex, text

I am trying to extract values from a given text.

Here is the text:

```
String 1: $.675.00 was spent on your CAPITAL ONE CREDIT Card ending 2123 on 2015-05-04:15:28:08 at Best Buy

String 2: $ 1,310.00 was spent on your Credit Card 5178XXXXXXXX6040 on MAY-04-15 at Amazon Stores.
```

I want to extract the following from string:

1. Amount after $
2. Credit Card text
3. Credit card number (in this case - 2123 or 5178XXXXXXXX6040)
4. at which place (in this case Best Buy or Amazon Stores).

To start I was trying extract all the numbers from the string: I tried the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string1);
Log.e("Value","from String"+m.group(0));
```

I am always getting the following error:

```
05-05 10:09:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13618): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
05-05 10:09:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13618):    at java.util.regex.Matcher.ensureMatch(Matcher.java:471)
05-05 10:09:35.532: E/AndroidRuntime(13618):    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:578)
```

Why isn't it matching even though the text has numbers?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734989/extract-numbers-from-an-alpha-numeric-string-using-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @justhecuke told there is no strict format for your string values to split using Patterns so I did using String functions, give a try

```
    String crType1 = "CREDIT Card ending ";//mind the space at end
    String crType2 = "Credit Card ";//mind the space at end

    String rate, cardNo, at;

    if (string1.contains(crType1)) {
        rate = getStringValue(string1, "$", " ");
        cardNo = getStringValue(string1, crType1, " ");
        at = getAddress(string1);
    } else {
        rate = getStringValue(string1, "$", " ");
        cardNo = getStringValue(string1, crType2, " ");
        at = getAddress(string1);
    }

    System.out.println(String.format("Rate : %s Card No : %s Address : %s", rate, cardNo, at));
```

Methods

```
public static String getAddress(String string) {
    return string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("at") + 2, string.length()).trim();
}

public static String getStringValue(String string, String startString, String endString) {
    int startAt = string.indexOf(startString) + startString.length();
    int endAt = string.indexOf(endString, startAt);
    return string.substring(startAt, endAt).trim();
}
```

Comment: Great. I am not getting any amount value for crtype2? That is 1,310?

Comment: What happens if we have another format of string which is like this: String 1: $.675.00 was spent on your CAPITAL ONE CREDIT Card ending 2123 on 2015-05-04:15:28:08 at Best Buy. Thanks for shopping etc. I don't want this string to come up (Thanks for shopping etc). I tried give lastindex even for this didn't work. Let me know!

Comment: you have to get index of Thanks. like this  `return string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("at") + 2, string.lastIndexOf("Thanks")).trim();`

Answer (score 0):

By the time you call `m.group(0)` you haven't actually told it to try to match stuff yet. This is why it gives you an IllegalStateException.

Try:

```
while(m.find()) {
  Log.e("Value",String.format("From String: '%s'", m.group()));
}
```

Comment: Got it. But this extracts value like one by one. How to get whole values like for String 1: 675.00, 2123, 2015-05-04:15:28:08 instead now it is coming like 675, 00, 2123, 2015, 05, 04, 15, 28, 08.

Comment: Well, it depends on what the format of the strings are. You can't parse a string if there isn't some sort of strict format that it sticks to, Perhaps you should publish that first.

Comment: I didn't understand this.. What do you mean by you should publish that first?

Comment: In order for a regex to work, there needs to be some sort of format to the string. Some guarantees that, for instance, you will always get something like "$123.45" instead of "$.123.45". I noticed that String 1 had this latter format, which caused me to ask this clarifying question.

In order to parse, there needs to be a pattern to parse.