# Show only numbers from text

Tags: java, android

I have a string that both the letter and the number.

As shown below:

[image]

I want to separate numbers from letters and When the user clicks the numbers
these numbers are displayed on the screen as buttons.

Such as following photos:

[image]
[image]

I have a activity that takes this string to another activity.

Basically what I should do? thanks.

My Activity1:

```
public class BoxActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.box);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
        String strBox = bundle.getString("fln");
        textView.setText(strBox);
    }

}
```

My Activity2

```
public class SmsInbox extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private static SmsInbox inst;
ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView smsListView;
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

public static SmsInbox instance() {
    return inst;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    inst = this;
}

DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_inbox);
    smsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SmsList);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsMessagesList);
    smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getBaseContext(), "android.permission.READ_SMS") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null,
                null, null);

        int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");

        if (indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst()) return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            String str = "?????? ??: " + cursor.getString(indexAddr) +
                    "\n" + cursor.getString(indexBody) + "\n";
            arrayAdapter.add(str);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}

public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
    arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    try {
        String[] smsMessages = smsMessagesList.get(pos).split("\n");
        String address = smsMessages[0];
        String smsMessage = "";
        for (int i = 1; i < smsMessages.length; ++i) {
            smsMessage += smsMessages[i];
        }
       /* String smsMessageStr = address + "\n";
        smsMessageStr += smsMessage;
        Toast.makeText(this, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       */
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, BoxActivity.class);
        String strBox = smsMessage;
        intent.putExtra("fln", strBox);
        startActivity(intent);
        /*Pattern isnumbers = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+$");
        Matcher numberMatch = isnumbers.matcher(strBox);

        if(numberMatch.matches()){
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + numberMatch, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } */

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menuRight) {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        } else {
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.Home_page) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.not_pay) {

        if (SmsInbox.this.drawer != null && SmsInbox.this.drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            SmsInbox.this.drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            SmsInbox.this.startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

        }

    } else if (id == R.id.date_pay) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.bill_sms) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.help_menu) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.for_us) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);

    } else if (id == R.id.exit_app) {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558432/extracting-a-number-from-a-string-in-java and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734989/extract-numbers-from-an-alpha-numeric-string-using-android...

Answer (score 0):

you should use Regex to exgtract Numbers from String

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("There are more than -2 and less than 12 numbers here");
while (m.find()) {
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

on view click listener you can do this.

```
@Override
void onClick(View view){
String allTxt = editText.getText.toString()
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(allTxt);
    while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());//here are the numbers then you can set it to another TextView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "test-asdfdfg 455 yuoyr 4";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " "); 
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

> Output [455, 4] use this array to show chooser